# Idiomaticité très douteuse : « transporter est lourd »

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, france

Dans un article sur « [The Oregon Trail](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/voyage/actualite/cannibalisme-et-massacres-la-sombre-histoire-de-la-piste-de-l-oregon/ss-AA17SIv7?ocid=msedgntp&cvid=216980313247476c9b1ec8145cfde785&ei=89#image=12) » on peut lire ceci.

- Les pionniers devaient traverser de longues étendues de terre dépourvues d'arbres et transporter du bois était trop lourd, alors ils utilisaient des excréments d'animaux (principalement des bisons) pour faire leurs feux.

On doit entendre par cela que « transporter quelque chose peut être lourd ». À mon avis cette construction est aberrante, mais il serait utile d'avoir la confirmation de lecteurs aguerris, ou chose surprenante, la confirmation que ce type d'agencement de termes est acceptable.

Comment: sur le principe "faire ceci était trop contraignant" a un construction identique et ne choque pas. Peut être que la gêne vient de la suspicion de confusion entre la lourdeur de la tâche (transporter) et la lourdeur du matériaux de la part de l'auteur/traducteur ?

Comment: On trouve la formulation « X était trop lourd à transporter » cependant. La poids de l'objet peut rendre son transport _difficile_. Ah, ok, la lourdeur de la tâche peut-être, bien vu.

Comment: Il est probable que "star insider" qui a rédigé l'article utilise un traducteur automatique. Car bien que la lourdeur de la tâche soit une théorie, il me semble qu'on est plutôt en présence d'une erreur de traduction. Un francophone aurait écrit "transporter du bois était trop fatiguant/contraignant/etc."

Comment: Je trouve aussi que quelque chose ne va pas. On peut dire qu'une tâche est lourde, mais associé à "transporter du bois", il y a une collision avec le sens "le bois était trop lourd à transporter", et "lourd" ne devrait pas pouvoir prendre ce sens dans cette formulation. Il me semble clair que l'auteur a voulu dire "le bois était trop lourd à transporter" mais sa formulation ne permet pas ce sens-là.